# iOS app and memory: chat app and sending of audio files

Tags: ios, swift, audio, memory, firebase-storage

I have an ios chat app where the users can send each other short audio messages which they can also record in the app (which is a pretty standard functionality in today's apps). I am synchronising the audio files via firebase storage. The audio files are short and not large, say 1-2 mb in size.

When playing back the audio files, they are not saved locally but they are loaded from firebase storage into memory and are then played on the receiving device. It all works fine.

My question: when are the audio files deleted from memory? Is there a risk that, when a users receives too many consecutive audio messages, this crashes the app even though the individual files are very small in size?

I am downloading to memory as described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files

```
// Create a reference to the file you want to download
let islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg")

// Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
    islandRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
  }
}
```

Comment: It all depends on your code which you haven't included in your question.

Comment: So long as you are successfully freeing the memory back to the operating system/runtime (which, in this case, unless you're doing something weird, probably just means making sure you aren't keep references to now unneeded objects), you should be fine.